# DB2 SQL extract only month and year from date column

Tags: sql, database, date, db2

I trying to **group by** month and year from MGMOV00F table - date column is DTMOMM, trying the syntax below but still getting error: argument 1 of function year not valid, anybody help please ?

[image]

Comment: DB@ supports the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions, so these should work.

Comment: try this DT01MM > #20160101#

Comment: error: column #20160101#  not in specified tables

Comment: yes should work but i am not using right syntax tried YEAR (yy, yyyy) too, same error

Comment: Are you sure `DTMOMM` is of the `DATE` data type? `DT01MM` is not.

Comment: yes DT01MM = creation date and DTMOMM = change date, so yes you are right i dont need DT01MM

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your dealing with an actual date data type?

Given the `WHERE DT01MM > '20160101'`

It would appear to me you're dealing with character columns; since AFAIK DB2 won't implicitly cast `'20160101'` to date like it would `'2016-01-01'`.

That being the case, your task is easy.  Simply substring the first 6 characters..

Comment: ok please forget DT01MM as i dont need it anymore (its date of creation) i need only - and group by date (year,month) DTOMM. records in DOTMM written as 20,160,101 (01 01 2016)

Comment: If `DOTMM` is truly `20,160,101` then it's not a date data type either.  That's a numeric value.  You won't be able to use `YEAR()` or `MONTH()`.  But `SUBSTRING(DIGITS(DOTMM),1,6)` would give you what you want.

Comment: if i use select: CDARMM, CDMGMM, CAMOMM, QTMOMM, SUBSTRING(DIGITS(DOTMM),1,6)   
error: 1 is not valid token
sorry but not really a SQL pro, know only basic tasks

Answer (score 0):

Selects count of month-year (m-yyyy) ordered by number of matches:

```
SELECT valid_from, COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT ( 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM valid_from) 
        CONCAT '-' CONCAT
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM valid_from)
    ) AS valid_from
    FROM some_table NOLOCK
) as s 
GROUP BY s.valid_from 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Result:

[image]